# Is there any way to prevent static variable value collision?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a class that has a ton of static values and am curious if there's any built in mechanism whereby I can have Eclipse throw an error if two of them have the same value.

If not, what would be a rational alternative to this (other than just being hyper vigilant in not accidentally assigning the same value)?

Comment: `I have a class that has a ton of static values` just to let you know that static variables are not garbage collected and are in the memory till the point class is there in memory even if they are not required. An unnecessary memory overhead

Comment: Whether they are an unnecessary memory overhead depends on the situation; there are situations in which static values are extremely useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely Eclipse (or any other IDE, for that matter) will not have specific tools to detect this.

You could build an unit test that goes though the static values using [Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) and fails the unit test if duplicates are found. This way you'll at least know if there are duplicates.

Comment: thanks... I was starting to suspect that this is going to be my only option... was holding out hope that Eclipse had some hidden feature (it has SO many!) that would handle this at compile time, so I wouldn't have to wait till runtime to find this out.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class UniqueStaticVariables {

  private final static UniqueHashMap<String,String> values = 
        new UniqueHashMap<String,String>();

  static {
    values.put("FIRST_VALUE", "a");
    values.put("SECOND_VALUE", "b");
    values.put("THIRD_VALUE", "a");
  }

  public static String get(String key) {
    return values.get(key);
  }

  private static class UniqueHashMap<K,E> extends HashMap<K,E> {

    @Override
    public E put(K key, E value) {
        if(!containsValue(value)) {
            return super.put(key, value);
        }
        return null;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(UniqueStaticVariables.get("FIRST_VALUE"));
    System.out.println(UniqueStaticVariables.get("SECOND_VALUE"));
    System.out.println(UniqueStaticVariables.get("THIRD_VALUE"));
  }
}
```

Comment: yeah, I was thinking it might come to this... I was hoping to avoid having to wait till runtime to find out that I have value overlap.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this statically. What you can do is add a unit test that iterates over all these fields using reflection and looks for duplicates by adding them to a Set.

Answer (score 0):

Not that this is a 100% solution, but at least for String constants, using a public static enum works quite well...

```
public static enum labels{
 A,
 B,
 C
};
```

These can't overlap and their string representation can be pulled via `.name()`.

Obviously they can't have any values other than what they actually look like but that actually works perfectly for my situation.

I'm new to enum, so, if someone has a reason why I shouldn't handle this in this manner, I'd love to know why.